# Delegate click event causes events firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use event delegation to add items to the DOM that can use the click event, it works, but it fires events twice on the second click.

**console output:**

```
25-06-2015
Object {option: "2", date: "25-06-2015", callback: "dialog"}
26-06-2015
Object {option: "2", date: "25-06-2015", callback: "dialog"}
Object {option: "2", date: "26-06-2015", callback: "dialog"}
```

**code**:

```
$(document).on("click", ".action", function(e){
    var target = $(this).data("target");

    console.log(target);

    var dialog = $('#dialog');

    dialog.find(".form-errors").html('');
    dialog.show();

    dialog.find('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var params = {
            'option': $(this).find('#option').val(),
            'target': target,
            'callback': 'dialog'
        };

        console.log(params);

        // call backend
        API(action, params)
    });

});
```

I tried to add this line, but it doesn't solve my problem

```
$(document).on("click", ".action", function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    ...
```

**new output** (watching closely, it sends the old date twice):

```
25-06-2015
Object {option: "2", date: "25-06-2015", callback: "dialog"}
26-06-2015
Object {option: "2", date: "25-06-2015", callback: "dialog"}
```

Comment: Try with `dialog.find('form').off('submit').submit(function(e){`

Comment: So every time you click on `.action`, you bind to form submit? Surely you only want to do that once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you click on `action` element of Following statements bind events with the element `dialog`, so with every click new `submit` is attached with the element.

```
dialog.find('form').submit(function(e){
```

You need to remove the previous event handlers using [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/). So use the following statement:

```
dialog.find('form').off('submit').submit(function(e){
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you have binded the event twice.

```
Solution 1: try to put e.preventDefault(); and return false;
Solution 2: try unbinding the event 
$(".action").unbind('click'); 

(or)

$(document).off('click', '.action');
```